# Load different wifi signal strength images based on signal strength in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to display images (basic images which represent wifi signal strength) on my android application. I have tried implementing that with the below code

```html
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wifi_row, parent, false);
  S_ID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SSID);
  BSSID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.BSSID);
  wifi_strength = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wifi_signal);
  wifi_lock = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wifi_lock);
  S_ID.setText(my_array.get(position));
  BSSID.setText(wifiScanList.get(position).BSSID);
  
  
  int current_level = 5;
  int signal_level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(mainWifiObj
    .getConnectionInfo().getRssi(), current_level);
  int signal_difference = (signal_level * 100) / current_level;
  
  Log.d("Signal_level", String.valueOf(signal_level));

  if (signal_difference >= 100) {
   wifi_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.wifi_signal_4);
  } else if (signal_difference >= 75) {
   wifi_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.wifi_signal_3);
  } else if (signal_difference >= 50) {
   wifi_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.wifi_signal_2);
  } else if (signal_difference >= 25) {
   wifi_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.wifi_signal_1);
  }
```

Below is my receiver class

```html
protected void onPause() {
 unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
 super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume() {
 registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
   WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
 super.onResume();
}

class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
 public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
  wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
  for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
   my_array.add((wifiScanList.get(i)).SSID);
  }
  myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
}
```

But it always display a full signal wifi image even for the weakest wifi network.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by myself. Used an hashMap to store the SSID and the corresponding signal strength. In the getView method I retrieved the signal level (value) using the SSID (Key).

Below code worked for me

```html
 int wifiSignalLevel = wifi_level.get(my_array.get(position));

        Log.d(my_array.get(position) + " Strength ",
                String.valueOf(wifiSignalLevel));

        if (wifiSignalLevel >= -70) {
            wifi_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.wifi_signal_4);
        } else if (wifiSignalLevel >= -80) {
            wifi_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.wifi_signal_3);
        } else if (wifiSignalLevel >= -90) {
            wifi_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.wifi_signal_2);
        } else if (wifiSignalLevel >= -100) {
            wifi_strength.setImageResource(R.drawable.wifi_signal_1);
        }
```